# Weird artifacting when baking my normals

Tags: uv, artifacts, retopology

So, I'm attempting to bake a high poly onto a retopo version. I am running into issues, however, where the baked normals looks kind of blocky in parts instead of smooth. I'm kind of new to retopology and know parts of my model looks strange on the sides (it's a sweater where most of the material is gonna be covered by a jacket so I didn't bother being perfect in those spots).

[image]

Comment: the retopo version is a bit messy but shade smooth it try a new bake maybe? If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Oh, so I did the shade smooth at one point and it does look better. But if I want to eventually import this character's clothing into Unreal Engine, will the smooth shading continue to take effect? Also, my file is ~125 mb, so I don't think I can upload it to pasteall. Is there a workaround? I guess I could delete the highpoly mesh from the file but maybe that would delete the purpose of this?

Comment: fixed the image attachment issue. sorry about the imgur link!

Comment: Thanks for the fix :-) If the file is too big for pasteall.org you could share it by Google drive, dropbox or a file hoster like mega.nz or wetransfer.com

Comment: I don't know anything about Unreal, I guess you can shade smooth in Unreal. As Blunder says try another platform.

Comment: Thanks moonboots, I hope Unreal has that feature if all else fails haha! Also, here is the google drive link (file is slightly bigger 'cause I needed to pack all the files into it). Also note there is a texture in there that is imported from Substance. It's separate from the baked normals I'm having issues with though. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X8hGhwD0DTNaZ33CaeTkI6qp0nSIfGpq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So once you shade smooth the bake looks ok. I think you don't have to worry about Unreal as it will keep the Blender shading. You could probably simplify the topology but that's another question...

Comment: Hey that's a good enough answer for me! Whatever shortcuts I can take to help with the final product sounds awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So once you shade smooth the low-poly, the bake looks ok. I think you don't have to worry about Unreal as it will keep the Blender shading. You could probably simplify the topology but that's another question.